# Bootstrap card put img on full size width of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap card https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/ to show a image,the problem is on bootstrap templete it just add a margin , I would like to make only  the image to stay o full width of the div, if somebody have a solution it would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- card documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/ -->

<section >
 
 <div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-header" style="background-color:white">
  
   
     Card Header
     
  <div class="card-body">
  <center>
  
  <!-- img I need full page size on card body -->
<div class="view overlay zoom">
    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/6-col/img%20(131).jpg" class="img-fluid " alt="smaple image">
    </div>  </center>
  
    <p class="card-text">card description</p>
    <div class="card-footer text-muted" style="background-color: white">card footer</div>
   
</section>
```

Comment: "To stay full width of the div". which div are you referring to? `<div class="view overlay zoom" />` or `<div class="card" />`? By the way, in your HTML layout, you have `.card-body` nested inside `.card-header`.

Comment: the div is the '<div class="card-body">'

Comment: `<div class="card-body" />` has default 1.25 rem padding there (not margin). Do you not care about the padding and just want the image to be absolute 100% width of that, or you do want to accommodate the padding?

Comment: yes how to  to accommodate the padding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bootstarp class `p-0` to remove the padding from the card and `w-100` on the image to take full width of `100%`

See code snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section>

  <div class="card text-center p-0">
    <div class="card-header" style="background-color:white">
      Card Header
    </div>
    <div class="card-body p-0">
      <div class="view overlay zoom">
        <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/6-col/img%20(131).jpg" class="img-fluid w-100" alt="smaple image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="card-text">card description</p>
    <div class="card-footer text-muted" style="background-color: white">card footer</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Great, but I still have a margin from the page how to solve this?

Comment: You want the card to take full width?

Comment: yeah, only the image exactly, but no problem if make all card full width

Comment: Since you want the card to take full page, you don't need `mr-auto ml-auto`, i only added it to center the card for demo purpose

Answer (score 1):

To make the image 100% width of the `.card-body`, it's as simple as adding `.w-100` class to the image to make it 100% width all the time.

```
<div class="card text-center">
    <div class="card-header" style="background-color:white">
        Card Header
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <center>
            <div class="view overlay zoom">
                <img src="" class="img-fluid w-100" alt="smaple image">
            </div>
        </center>
        <p class="card-text">card description</p>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted" style="background-color: white">card footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/qh6o2gyz/3/

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine, but I still see a blank margin on the html, how to solve this?